# Licensing of programs my Problem

Tags: licensing, ide

I am to create a game / program but my problem is about licensing which are:

1. My IDE codeblock & Dev-C++ does **NOT** allow my created program to be release as closed-source.
2. I want to create a commercial/proprietary Program or Game so I can sell it.
3. What IDEs, libraries(GUI, Physics, etc) you can recommend to me based on my problem? Can you recommend websites which explains in layman terms the different kinds of licenses.
4. Also does LGPL license allow me this?
5. Comment any further information you want to share with me.

*You can **IGNORE** question #3, if it's not appropriate in this site.

Thank you

Comment: For 1. read http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhatCaseIsOutputGPL

Comment: Ignoring the parts that are not questions, or not fit for this site, only number 4 remains. And that's not gamedev related. Voting to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mistaken. Software development tools licensed under the GNU GPL can be used to create software under other licenses, even proprietary ones. [The official FAQ about the GNU GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#CanIUseGPLToolsForNF) reads:

> **Question:** Can I use GPL-covered editors to develop non-free programs? Can I use GPL-covered tools to compile them?
>
> **Answer:** Yes, because the copyright on the editors and tools does not cover the code you write. Using them does not place any restrictions, legally, on the license you use for your code.

But there are problems when you use GNU GPL libraries, because these must not be used for programs under different licenses. Fortunately the libstdc++ (The C++ standard library which ships with Code::Blocks and Dev-C++) is not licensed under the GPL but under the [LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License). That means you may link programs against it and license them under any license you want (as long as you aren't modifying the libstdc++ itself, but even when you would be crazy enough to do that, you would only have to license your modified library under the LGPL, not the game you made with it).